# Define and solve nested non-linear ODE in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm given the differential equation `y'' = -g + a(t)/m` with `a(t) = k*y'^2` where `y` is a function of `t` (time). My initial conditions are `y(0) = 600;` and `y'(0) = 0;`

In MATLAB I know how to define `y''` with

```
ydd = diff(y,t,2) == -g + a(t)/m;
```

but I'm lost at the fact that this is a 'nested' non linear differential equation and I'm not quite sure how to define it, let alone, solve it in MATLAB.

Comment: Just define `a(t)` and call `dsolve` ... ?

Comment: I did not know i could just define `y'` as `y' = diff(y,t)`... @TroyHaskin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better first order system is

```
v' = -g + k/m*v^2
y' = v
```

as there is no longer a third unknown function `a(t)` involved.

---

Challenge: Solve the first equation manually via separation of variables and partial fraction decomposition or identifying the scaling for the Area tangent hyperbolicus as the integral for the side of `v`.

Comment: This is a great answer.  I would accept it over mine.  I may have been first, but this one is better.

Answer (score 1):

This is two coupled first order ODEs.

Let `z = y'`.  Then you have:

```
z' = -g + a(t)/m
y' = sqrt(a(t)/k)
```

You need initial conditions `y(0)=600` and `z(0)=0`.

That equation `z(0)=0` implies that `a(0)/m = g`.  Solve for `a(0) = gm`.

These are the equations you need to solve.

Comment: I have updated my question with the initial conditions

Comment: @Ortix92 so why don't you solve it then with those conditions? This is how you, mathematically, should do it.